# C# How to get an asynchronous call in IObservable wait for other async call execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an application with 2 async calls and I need to wait for the first one to complete before OnNext in the second workflow is fired so that if first one errors then second isn't executed. But currently second one executes before first call returns. Given below is the simplified code so please help me in applying suitable wait mechanism here. I tried await but could not get that working.

```
 public IObservable<dataType> MainMethod()
        {
          return Observable.Create<dataType>(
           (observer) =>
           {
             AsyncCommandClass cmd = new AsyncCommandClass("commandmethodPAth");
             command.CommandCompleted += (sender, args) =>
             {
               ///handle failure
             };

             this.ExecuteAsyncCommand(cmd);

             // Execute the other internal asynchronous workflow 
            this.Workflow2()
             .AsSequential()
             .Subscribe(
             (next) =>
             {
                     },
           (error) =>
             {
              observer.OnError(error);
              },
             () =>  // completed
              {
                 observer.OnNext(new dataType());  // this call should not execute if previous one errors
                 observer.OnCompleted();
              });
              return () =>
                    {
                    };
                });
        }
```

Comment: See following example.  Look at the method WaitOne : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx.  Here is the documentation on WaitOne : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could investigate using the TaskCompletionSource for this: http://pmichaels.net/2016/06/01/taskcompletionsource/